# Image won't change when key is pressed

Tags: java, processing

I am making my own little copy of Mario that I started today, and I am stuck on a little animation.

When `UP` is pressed, Mario jumps, but the sprite won't change.

I have tried if-else to set it, but it's not working:

```java
PImage brick1;
PImage bg;
PImage Flag;
float playerX;
float playerY;
float brickX;
float Lives;
float Level;
float Time;
void setup(){

size(1000,800);
smooth();
if (keyPressed){
    if (keyCode == UP){
        bg = loadImage("Mario3.png");
    }
}else{
    bg = loadImage("Mario1.png");
}
```

I expect the image to change while <kbd>UP</kbd> is held down, but it says the "Mario1.png" sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to implement a `draw` function.

Load the images in `setup`:

```java
PImage bg1, bg3;
void setup() {

  size(1000, 800);
  smooth();

  bg1 = loadImage("Mario1.png");
  bg3 = loadImage("Mario3.png");
}
```

And draw the proper image dependent on the state of [`keyPressed`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed.html) and [`keyCode`](https://processing.org/reference/keyCode.html).
Use [`image()`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) to draw an image to the display:

e.g.

```py
void draw() {

    background(0);

    if (keyPressed && keyCode == UP) {
        image(bg3, 0, 0);
    } else {
        image(bg1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```